# Count and Select Object in ActiveRecord with 1 query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We have objects that we want to represent in stacks (think of stacking items in an MMO). There will be duplicate rows.

Let's say our owned_objects table looks like this.

```
user_id | object_id
1       | 27
1       | 27
3       | 46
3       | 46
5       | 59
```

I want the query to do

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  object_id,
  count(*) AS count
FROM owned_objects
GROUP BY
  user_id,
  object_id;
```

And return either the 3 distinct `OwnedObject`s (or even just getting the distinct `Object`s would work too) and a count associated with it.

I know this is possible with SQLAlchemy, but can you do it with ActiveRecord?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about …

```
@objects = user.objects.all(:select => "count(*) as count, objects.*", :group => :object_id)
```

… or similar?

You can then retrieve the counts by a dynamically created attribute on each object:

```
@object.first.count # the "stack depth" of the first object.
```

This assumes either a `has_and_belongs_to_many :objects` or a `has_many :objects, :through => :owned_objects` on user.

Comment: Hmm, so I tried that and it returns the objects, and performs the correct query, but how does one retrieve the count from that call?

Comment: It should be in the #count attribute of the respective objects.

Comment: Don't think that's working because the reflection doesn't see a column called count. By `#count` you're referring to just the class method, `count`, courrect?

Comment: No, count should be defined dynamically as an attribute on each returned object. ActiveRecord can be clever like that.

Comment: Worked for me - was able to setup a scope on a model `M` with `scope :foo, self.select("count(*) as count, object_id").group(:object_id)` and then could use with `@foo = M.foo` and access `@foo.count` and `foo.object_id`

Answer (score 0):

Found *a* solution, but not sure if it's the cleanest (hope it isn't).

Basically I created a SQL view that does that query and created a model for it. There's a plugin for rails that recognizes views on migrations.